# Is there an integral representation of the capacitance matrix?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

Suppose we have conductors $\{S_1, S_2,\ldots,S_N\}$ with boundaries $\{\partial S_1, \partial S_2,\ldots,\partial S_N\}$.
These conductors are suspended in vacuum.
Is there an integral over these bodies and/or their boundaries that provides the capacitance matrix of the system?

Comment: The capacitance matrix depends largely on the permittivity of the interior.
It requires its distribution to be specified.

Although I do not know the answer to your question,
there is a numerical method for calculating the capacitance matrix.
I.e., equating the stored energy expressed in terms of $V$ and $C$
and the stored energy in terms of $E$ and $D$ field integration over the internal space.
$E$ and $D$ are calculated by numerical solvers.

Comment: I did a colab notebook with a possible BEM formulation for this problem. This is a preliminary version, it may contain some mistakes (signs maybe), but it should highlight everything you need https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1U6Z_VAH0VdKXIiAF1-YO5RDzCT3VbPhK?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a try, even if this is not my main field of interest, since I worked a bit on boundary element methods. I guess that you can only find a solution using a surface integral if the permittivity $\varepsilon$ is uniform in the region of space where you're inserting the conductors of the capacitor.

**Governing equations.** Let's denote with $\Omega_0$ the region of space outside the conductors, $\Omega_i$ the volume of the $i^{th}$ conductor, whose surface is labelled $\partial \Omega_i$.

- Assuming the laws of electrostatics hold
  \begin{aligned}
    \nabla \cdot \mathbf{d} & = \rho \\
    \nabla \times \mathbf{e} + \underbrace{\partial_t\mathbf{b}}_{\partial_t \equiv 0} & = 0 \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \mathbf{e} = - \nabla v \ ,
  \end{aligned}
- assuming that the permittivity $\varepsilon$ is uniform in $\Omega_0$ and the constitutive law reads $\mathbf{d} = \varepsilon \mathbf{e}$
- assuming there is no free charge in the space $\Omega_0$, $\rho = 0$ in $\Omega_0$, so that we get a Laplace equation for the potential

  $- \nabla^2 v = \rho = 0$
- remembering that there is no free charge inside a conductor, except for a very thin layer at the surface, and the electric field is $\mathbf{e} = 0$ inside, we can:

  - recall that the surface of a conductor is equipotential, i.e. the value of the electric potential on each surface is uniform,

    $v(\mathbf{x})|_{\mathbf{x} \in \partial \Omega_i} = v_i$
  - use the jump conditions at the interface to get another boundary condition relating the normal derivative of the

    $\varepsilon \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbf{e} = \varepsilon \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla v = \varepsilon \partial_n v = \sigma$.

Now, putting everything together, we get a Laplace equation for $v$ and its boundary conditions

\begin{cases}
-\nabla^2 v = 0   \quad \text{in} \Omega_0 \\
v(\mathbf{x})|_{\Gamma_i} = v_i \\
\varepsilon \partial_n v(\mathbf{x})|_{\partial \Omega_0} = \varepsilon \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla v(\mathbf{r}) = \sigma_i(\mathbf{x})
\end{cases}

**Solution using Green's function.** It's now possible to find a solution by collocation, after having exploited the properties of the Green's function for Laplace equation, $-\nabla^2 G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}_0) = \delta(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_0)$.

Introducing the factor $E(\mathbf{r}_0)$ that takes care if the point $\mathbf{r}_0$ is inside the domain, on the boundary, or outside the domain, and performing integration by part, we can write

\begin{aligned}
  E(\mathbf{r}_0)v(\mathbf{r}_0) &= \int_{\Omega_0} \delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0) v(\mathbf{r}) dV_{\mathbf{r}} = \\
& = - \int_{\Omega_0} \nabla^2 G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}_0)  v(\mathbf{r}) dV_{\mathbf{r}} = \\
& = - \int_{\partial \Omega_0} v(\mathbf{r}) \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}_0) dS_{\mathbf{r}} + 
  \int_{\partial \Omega_0} G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}_0) \underbrace{\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla v(\mathbf{r})}_{=\frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon}} dS_{\mathbf{r}} - \int_{\Omega_0} \underbrace{\nabla^2 v(\mathbf{r})}_{=0}  G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}_0) dV_{\mathbf{r}}
\end{aligned}.

**Approximation/discretization**. Now, you can use an approximation to find the charge distribution on each surface. As an example, you can divide the surfaces of the conductors in $N$ elements, $E_e$, $e = 1:N$. Assuming you know the potential on the surface $v_i$ (you can prescribe them in an experiment), you have $N$ unknowns, namely $\sigma_e$, for $e=1:N$. Thus, you use collocation method and choose $N$ different points $\mathbf{r}_0$ (usually collocated with the centers of your elements) to get a system of $N$ equations.

Briefly, we can recast the equation above for an element $e \in \Gamma_i$

\begin{equation}
E(\mathbf{r}_e) v_i =
- \sum_j v_j \int_{\Gamma_j}  \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}_e) dS_{\mathbf{r}} + 
  \sum_{f = 1:N} \int_{E_f} G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}_e) \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon} \sigma_f dS_{\mathbf{r}}  \qquad \text{for $e = 1:N$}
\end{equation}

Assuming uniform charge density on each element, we can recast the equation above in matrix form as:
\begin{equation}
  [ \underline{\underline{E}}_{ei} + \underline{\underline{D}}_{ei} ] \underline{V}_i = \underline{\underline{S}}_{ef} \underline{\sigma}_f
 \qquad , \qquad (\underline{\underline{E}}+\underline{\underline{D}}) \underline{V} = \underline{\underline{S}} \underline{\sigma}.
\end{equation}

Now, it's possible to find the vector of the source density over each element $\sigma$, solving this linear system

\begin{equation}
\underline{\sigma} = \underline{\underline{S}}^{-1} (\underline{\underline{E}}+\underline{\underline{D}}) \underline{V} \ .
\end{equation}

Once you know the charge density, you can find the total charge on every conductor by integration,

\begin{equation}
 Q_i = \int_{\Gamma_i} \sigma(\mathbf{r}) \ ,
\end{equation}

that can be written with matrix formalism as

\begin{equation}
\underline{Q} = \underline{\underline{P}} \underline{\sigma} 
\end{equation}

with the matrix $\underline{\underline{P}}$ performing the numerical integration.

Putting everything together, it's possible to relate the total charges on the conductors with their potentials as

\begin{equation}
  \underline{Q} = \underline{\underline{P}} \underline{\sigma} = 
  \underline{\underline{P}} \underline{\underline{S}}^{-1} (\underline{\underline{E}}+\underline{\underline{D}}) \underline{V} \ ,
\end{equation}

i.e.

\begin{equation}
  \underline{Q} = \underline{\underline{C}} \underline{V} \end{equation}

with the capacitance matrix

\begin{equation}
  \underline{\underline{C}} =
  \underline{\underline{P}} \underline{\underline{S}}^{-1} (\underline{\underline{E}}+\underline{\underline{D}}) \ .
\end{equation}

**Remark.** If you want non-zero values of the potential at the infinity (remember that potential is defined up to an additive constant), you need to treat the ``doublet'' integral contribution,
\begin{equation}
  -  v_{\infty} \underbrace{\int_{\partial \Omega_{\infty}} \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}_0) dS_{\mathbf{r}}}_{-1} = v_{\infty} \ .
\end{equation}
from the surface at the infinity as well, since the integral doesn't vanish but equals a round angle divided by $2 \pi$, i.e. equals $1$.

**Link.** You can find a preliminary version of a script evaluating the capacitance matrix for 2D problem in this Colab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jC8tPdOELI3cmCPXWLWKMsMTBgoqY1BF?usp=sharing

Comment: I am slowly working my way through your answer. Let me first ask about the function $E$. Is it correct that $E(r)=1$ if $r \in \Omega_0$ and 0 otherwise?

Comment: Yes, and if the point is on the boundary equals the fraction of the round angle seen by the point when looking into the domain, i.e. $1/2$ if it's on a smooth surface, $\theta/2\pi$ if it's a point where the boundary has an angle $\theta$